# Possible to extract only new words between 2 text files using git diff?

Tags: string, git, diff

I have two files, fileA and fileB. These are text files, each containing essentially one long string (a series of paragraphs).

I want to be able to show only the 'words' in fileB that are newly added/not contained in fileA. Browsing this forum I saw saw git diff as a suggested approach - using its word-diff argument, highlights in green the new words in fileB nicely.

I was wondering if there's a way to take this output and extract only the new additions in fileB, so that I could place this in a separate text file. To maybe help make this clearly, what I'm envisioning is something like the diff command given here as an answer (diff -U $(wc -l < fileA) fileA fileB | sed -n 's/^-//p' > fileC, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28158/is-there-a-tool-to-get-the-lines-in-one-file-that-are-not-in-another).

What would be especially useful was if there's a way to filter based on the length of the contiguous block of green-colored words (as I can 'filter' the sentences that are likely only in fileB and not in fileA).

Comment: This may be helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/392191/diff-to-show-only-the-additions-in-a-changed-file

Comment: Thanks, I saw that and maybe even more relevant was here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28158/is-there-a-tool-to-get-the-lines-in-one-file-that-are-not-in-another. What I was hoping was that there's an equivalent version for git diff as what Caleb described for using diff to extract only the differences between the files (diff -U $(wc -l < fileA) fileA fileB | sed -n 's/^-//p' > fileC)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wdiff`

```
> brew install wdiff            [On MacOS]
# yum install wdiff             [On CentOS/RHEL/Fedora]
# dnf install wdiff             [On Fedora 23+ version]
$ sudo apt-get install wdiff    [On Debian/Ubuntu/Mint]
```

Then foo file:

```
foo foo toto tutu
```

bar file:

```
foo bar toto tata tutu
```

To compare:

```
▶ wdiff /tmp/bar /tmp/foo
foo [-bar-] {+foo+} toto [-tata-] tutu
```

If you want color:

```
wdiff -n -w $'\033[0;31m' -x $'\033[0m' -y $'\033[0;32m' -z $'\033[0m' /tmp/bar /tmp/foo
```

[image]

Comment: In the above example, would it be possible to then extract only the 'green' foo as the output? Ideally in one command I'd be able to grab all newly added words and place in a few text file.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`--word-diff=porcelain`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-porcelain) to make extracting the individual changes easy to code. Each changed line is printed as a series of unchanged, removed and added words runs, with the line boundaries shown as a separate `~` line.

Comment: Hey thanks for letting me know about that. I was playing around with the output using the porcelain flag and I can use a command like follows to grep only the new additions to the file: !git diff --word-diff=porcelain fileA fileB | grep '^+' . This almost does exactly what I want - is there a way to subsequently grep only for strings > a certain number of characters (let's say 210?)? And similarly a way to remove the '+' in the output?

Comment: `sed` and `awk` are fundamental text-processing tools, they've got their fortes where one or the other are simply the best tool for the job, many things become oneliners or quick little five-liners; or `flex` might be easiest depending on what your end goal is here. Those tools would be worth almost any effort to master, and they're not hard.